# Yelp JSON output is not converting to ruby hash

Tags: ruby, oauth, rubygems, yelp

Here is my YELP client using signet but once I get response, I'm not able to convert to ruby hash to inspect response element.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'net/http'


client = Signet::OAuth1::Client.new(
  :client_credential_key =>
    'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  :client_credential_secret =>
    'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  :token_credential_key =>
    'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  :token_credential_secret => 
    'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
)
response = client.fetch_protected_resource(
  :uri => 'http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=food&location=san+francisco'
)
# The Rack response format is used here
status, headers, body = response
puts body["businesses"]
```

Error:
`[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)

Body prints fine in nice JSON format but I can do body["businesses"] for instance
JSON.parse(body).inspect is also not working.

Btw body outputs itself appears as JSON format but JSON.parse(body) doesn't produce hash

```
puts body

{"region":{"span":{"latitude_delta":0.0,"longitude_delta":0.0},"center":{"latitude":37.660418999999997,"longitude":-121.876508}},"total":853,"businesses":[{"rating":4.0,"mobile_url":"http://m.yelp.com/biz/TT1t4oHeZmqkoiuwgCN4bQ","rating_img_url":"http://media2.ak.yelpcdn.com/static/201012164084228337/img/ico/stars/stars_4.png","review_count":150,"name":"India Garden","rating_img_url_small":"http://media2.ak.yelpcdn.com/static/20101216418129184/img/ico/stars/stars_small_4.png","url":"http://www.yelp.com/biz/india-garden-pleasanton-2","phone":"9254854800","snippet_text":"We went to this place without seeing any reviews while we returning to San Jose from Cache Creek in Brooks. This place looks like a house which was...","image_url":"http://s3-media4.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/8iFj1S9YaU5IdUazwZOG8A/ms.jpg","snippet_image_url":"http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/photo/d2TovvsTn2eUw4xqTB4jyw/ms.jpg","display_phone":"+1-925-485-4800","rating_img_url_large":"http://media4.ak.yelpcdn.com/static/20101216169592178/img/ico/stars/stars_large_4.png","id":"india-garden-pleasanton-2","categories":[["Indian","indpak"],["Pakistani","pakistani"]],"location":{"cross_streets":"Main St & Neal St","city":"Pleasanton","display_address":["210 Rose Ave","(b/t Main St & Neal St)","Pleasanton, CA 94566"],"geo_accuracy":8,"postal_code":"94566","country_code":"US","address":["210 Rose Ave"],"coordinate":{"latitude":37.660418999999997,"longitude":-121.876508},"state_code":"CA"}}]}
```

Comment: Why do you use both Yajl *and* the standard JSON library? Use one *or* the other.

Comment: It didn't matter, I tried both individually.

Comment: rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.1/lib/json/common.rb:148:in `initialize': can't convert Array into String (TypeError)
 from /home/arun/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.1/lib/json/common.rb:148:in `new'
 from /home/arun/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.1/lib/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
 from yelp_test.rb:22:in `<main>'

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(body)["businesses"]`. That works on my end.

Comment: hmm not sure why it worked on yours and not mine   versions         rails -v Rails 3.1.1 Ruby -v = 1.9.2.... I'm getting same error with your suggestion.

Comment: Try `require "yaml"; puts YAML.dump body` (edit the question, don't put it in comments)

Answer (score 1):

Actually i'm pretty sure, that body is an Array at this point, since response contains four parts and not three, so the last two parts (an array) are put into the body-object.

Also Array is the only core-object i know, which complains about an [] parameter being not an integer. If it was a string, it would try a regex/contain match.

So to sum up, body is an Array with only one Value containing a String. So to get your Hash (from JSON) you have to `real_body = JSON.parse body[0]`. Then you should get your hash and
`real_body["businesses"]` puts your businesses (the output is rather long so i will not be posting it here)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I think body is indeed an array but length of this array is 1. puts body.count prints 1 and class is Array. There are only three response values. Any suggestion how can I get hold of businesses by using body["businesses"] and other fields

Comment: what is the class of the object in the array? 
maybe you should just try body[0]["businesses"]

Comment: puts body.class ===> Array    puts body[0]["businesses"] --> businesses

Comment: okay that actually makes sense, since your array only cotnains one object and this object is the string which you were searching for...
see edited answer above for an idea ;)

Comment: Helped me to find out. If I understand this problem correctly, it would be great to have an official json object format.

Answer (score 0):

body is a string at this point, not a hash.  The [] operator is complaining because the string [] operator only takes an integer, so it's trying to turn your string into an integer and failing.

edit: you can test this by just printing out body.class

Comment: Yes its an array but how do I get hold of body elements. JSON parsing is not working. I want to extract body["businesses"]